# IntelliJ Upload AppEngine Application stops in Authorization

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have a very simple Google AppEngine app in Intellij 13, Java 1.7 and when I click on Upload AppEngine Application, I get the prompt for google mail address and password (I'm sure that I give the correct username/password), and then the upload process goes no further than this:

> Beginning interaction for module default... sep 16, 2014 11:13:08 EM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
>
> Blockquote
>   WARNING: Error posting to URL:
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=mysimpleapp1&version=1&
>
> 401 Unauthorized Must authenticate first. This is try #0
>
> ---
>
> Password for myemailaddress@gmail.com: Email: Password for ***********:

It used to work a while ago without any problems. Does anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see this? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2033

Comment: Just press Return and then enter your credentials again. Idea will remember it until next restart.

Comment: Hi, I'm a representative of Google Cloud Support. Were you able to solve this issue following the recommendations by Mihail or Peter? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, no I could not solve this issue. I gave up and switched to a maven enabled project. Now I'm using command line "mvn appengine:update" to upload my app.